# Groupby filter ordering

Tags: jinja2

Is it possible to make the `groupby` filter order in descending order? I have a list of dictionaries from a SQL query and I want to group by date in descending date order. From the manual:

```
{% for group in persons|groupby('gender') %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}<ul>
    {% for person in group.list %}
        <li>{{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try applying the `reverse` filter to the `groupby('attribute')` filter (e.g., `{% for group in persons|groupby('gender')|reverse %}`)